# Get text in between <input> tag

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

How can I get the value between  tag. Here is the **HTML**...
Checkboxes value need to stored in List.

```
<div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth" style="height:180px;width:100%;">
   <div class="rcbCheckAllItems"><input type="checkbox" class="rcbCheckAllItemsCheckBox">Check All</div>
   <ul class="rcbList" style="list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;zoom:1;">
      <li class="rcbHovered "><input type="checkbox" class="rcbCheckBox">Dallas , Wanda</li>
      <li class="rcbItem "><input type="checkbox" class="rcbCheckBox">Parker , Tina</li>
      <li class="rcbItem "><input type="checkbox" class="rcbCheckBox">Plano , Samantha </li>
      <li class="rcbItem "><input type="checkbox" class="rcbCheckBox">Richardson , Christina</li>
      <li class="rcbItem "><input type="checkbox" class="rcbCheckBox">Dave , Test</li>
      <li class="rcbItem "><input type="checkbox" class="rcbCheckBox">clinician , test</li>
      <li class="rcbItem "><input type="checkbox" class="rcbCheckBox">Smith , Jasmin</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Please help me to find code. Binding language is **JAVA.**

My Sample code:-

```
List<WebElement> eles = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.rcbList > li"));

List<String> txts = new ArrayList<String>();
String script = "return arguments[0].lastChild.nodeValue;";
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Boolean stale = true;
for (WebElement ele : eles) {
    try {
        WebElement webEle = ele.findElement(By.className("rcbCheckBox"));
        if (webEle.getText().equals(sheetValue)) {
            String text = (String) js.executeScript(script, ele);
            txts.add(text.toString());
            String txt = text.toString();
            for (String texts : txts) {
                System.out.println("Print----------> " + texts);
            }
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            // if (text.equals(sheetValue)) {
            System.out.println("inside if" + webEle.getText().equals(sheetValue));
            ele.findElement(By.tagName("input")).click();
            ;
        } // ele.click();
        stale = false;
    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
        stale = true;
    }
}
```

I am stuck here now.

Comment: add complete HTML

Comment: I have added html

Comment: @reshmianeesh What exactly do you mean by **get the value between tag**? Are you trying to extract any `text`? Which _text_ / _texts_ ?

Comment: I mean text in between<input>tag. As it is checkbox i need to check it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text among in Tag is type of TextNode, not ElementNode. Selenium's find API can only  return ElementNode from HTML DOM Tree.

In order to access TextNode, you have to use JavaScript through `driver.executeScript()` as following:

```
List<WebElement> eles = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.rcbList > li"));

List<String> txts = new ArrayList<String>();
String script = "return arguments[0].lastChild.nodeValue;";
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
int length = eles.size();

for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
    WebElement ele = eles.get(i);
    String text = (String) js.executeScript(script, ele);
    if(text.equals(sheetValue)) {
       ele.findElement(By.cssSelector('input')).click();
       txts.add(text);
       // find all li again on page after click,
       // seems each click on checkbox caused page DOM tree changed
       eles = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.rcbList > li"));
    }

}
```

Or you can find the parent ElementNode of the TextNode, and get whole text of parent, then extract the partial text from whole text.

Comment: +1 from my side , I tested it and it worked fine . @reshmianeesh , kindly check this solution and accept it if it would resolve your problem.

Comment: Though you can use  for(String texts : txts){
          System.out.println(texts);
         }  for printing purpose.

Comment: You should type some wrong in your code,  double check it. Or show them in your question, I will find out the wrong place.

Comment: @Reshmi,  Please clarify what you want? From your question description you want to store the text of all checkbox. But from your given code,  you wan to choose the checkbox whose text is same as `sheetValue`.   If you want the former, the code in my answer should resolve it, rather than as your feedback `my code not work`

Comment: Code update as your want.  you can get the text of selected check box from variable `txts`.

Comment: After you choose checkbox, did the page change like refresh/ partial area load? And did you totally replace your given code with my code in answer.  your given code has wrong  place.

Comment: And how many checkbox you want to choose, if only one, it should not report `stale element reference` error.

Comment: Add one more line `eles = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.rcbList > li"));` inside `if . And change the loop iterate way. Try again

Comment: unknown error: Element <input type="checkbox" class="rcbCheckBox"> is not clickable at point (203, 452). Other element would receive the click: <li class="rcbItem ">...</li> error is coming now :(

Answer (score 0):

With `getText()` you can get the innerText of a WebElement. Since you dont have any text in the `<input>` tag I think you want to get the Attributes? 
If you want the Attributes of your WebElement you could use `getAttribute()`.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the Webelements List

```
   driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[1]/ul"));
```

Comment: Actually i am having list of checkboxes inside ui li tags. List<webElements> tags = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".rcbCheckBox")); syste.out.println(tags.get(i).getText()); => not print the test in between. Please help

Comment: Try this aswell    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".rcbHovered  > input [class = "rcbCheckBox"]")).gettext();

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
   List<WebElement> checkboxes=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='rcbList']/li"));
   for (WebElement checkbox: checkboxes) {
   System.out.println(checkbox.getText());
```

Comment: It doesnt worked..it is a List so getAttribute not worked.

Comment: try with getText()

Comment: List<WebElement> tags = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("//input[@class='rcbCheckBox']")); what to do for this?

Comment: xpath - //input[@class='rcbCheckBox'] is not working.. so i am not able to continue.

Answer (score 0):

With the explanation in the question and by seeing other answers, I think you want the HTML content between the HTML tags, that is -

- Check All
- Dallas , Wanda
- Parker , Tina
- Richardson , Chri
- Dave , Test
- clinician , test
- Smith , Jasmin

To get the above HTML contents, try using the following java code.

## Java code

```
final String regex = "(>\\w+((\\s\\W\\s)|(\\W)|(\\s))\\w+<)|(>\\w+<)";
final String string = "<div class=\"rcbScroll rcbWidth\" style=\"height:180px;width:100%;\">" +
    "<div class=\"rcbCheckAllItems\"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"rcbCheckAllItemsCheckBox\">Check All</div>" +
    "<ul class=\"rcbList\" style=\"list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;zoom:1;\">" +
    "<li class=\"rcbHovered \"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"rcbCheckBox\">Dallas , Wanda</li>" +
    "<li class=\"rcbItem \"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"rcbCheckBox\">Parker , Tina</li>" +
    "<li class=\"rcbItem \"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"rcbCheckBox\">Plano , Samantha </li>" +
    "<li class=\"rcbItem \"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"rcbCheckBox\">Richardson , Christina</li>" +
    "<li class=\"rcbItem \"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"rcbCheckBox\">Dave , Test</li>" +
    "<li class=\"rcbItem \"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"rcbCheckBox\">clinician , test</li>" +
    "<li class=\"rcbItem \"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"rcbCheckBox\">Smith , Jasmin</li>" +
    "<li class=\"rcbItem \"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"rcbCheckBox\">Smith,Jasmin</li>" +
    "<li class=\"rcbItem \"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"rcbCheckBox\">SmithJasmin</li>" +
    "</ul></div>";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

ArrayList<String> innerHTML = new ArrayList<>();

while (matcher.find()) {
    String html = matcher.group(0);
    html = html.substring(1, html.length()-1);
    System.out.println("Full match: " + html);
    // Now you have all the value in between tags in this ArrayList called innerHTML
    innerHTML.add(html);
}
```

## Sample output

```
Full match: Check All
Full match: Dallas , Wanda
Full match: Parker , Tina
Full match: Richardson , Christina
Full match: Dave , Test
Full match: clinician , test
Full match: Smith , Jasmin
```

Now, you can access these HTML content by iterating through `innerHTML` ArrayList. Hope it helped.

Comment: Sorry about the first line, I will edit it. Other than that do I need to improve anything? @cruisepandey

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and it will work.

```
List<WebElement> elementList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='rcbList']/li"));
List<String> valueList=new ArrayList<String>();

int size=elementList.size();

for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    valueList.add(elementList.get(i).getText());
}
```